# Changes to website not reflected when viewed

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-6

I have a silver light application accessed through an ASP.NET website. I edited the code behind .cs code file of one page to solve a bug and deployed the file by copying and replacing the old file.

Now the issue is, if browser to site through

`http://my-server-name/MyWebSite/`, i see the changes are applied but if i browse through

`http://my-server-name.mydomain.subdomain.mycompany.org/MyWebSite/`

the changes are not reflected. Does any one know what causes such behavior.

I have tried restarting the Application pool in IIS and also refreshing the website in IIS but with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Please try refreshing the client browser cache as the silverlight application might be cached on the client side when you have accessed the previous version through the second url before.